# SSL/TLS HeartBleed vulnerability

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, keytool, heartbleed-bug

I am using Https and Tcp over SSL in java application with keystores and truststores. I use selfsigned certificates generated by java keytool. I am came to know about HeartBleed vulnerability with openSSL, do I need to change any implementation from java side or I am on safe side. can anyone please give details.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java does not use OpenSSL, although some Java applications like Tomcat can. As you're using keystores and truststores, you must be using JSSE rather than OpenSSL.

Comment: I would add that, even if you're not using OpenSSL, this is still probably an opportune time to upgrade it on your server (but doing so is off topic for SO).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my question. Actually after reading long article about HeartBleed I am confused little. thanks for help.

Comment: @Jason If you're not using it how can you upgrade it?

Comment: @EJP, I wasn't very clear, I meant if it's already installed on your system, even if you're not using it, you should update it now.  On many systems it could be installed by default.